# Android RecyclerView Scroll Bug

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview

I'm not sure if I found a Bug in Androids new RecyclerView or I did something wrong.

I created a simple RecyclerView List as it's described in the example (http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#RecyclerView)

The list displays strings numbered from "Item 1" to "Item 9". If I begin to scroll, the indicator on the right jumps back to the top after I reached the second listitem.

Heres a picture:
[image: http://www11.pic-upload.de/21.10.14/mib95cped9x1.jpg]

As you can see, the scroll indicator and the second listitem are on top. On the last image the list is scrolled to the end but the indicator isn't.

Comment: if this code is using the July preview, it is a known bug. If you've created it with the preview released last friday, please submit a bug report in aosp tracker with a sample application. Thanks.